# javascript multidimensional array loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have some jquery code which I'm trying to re-write into basic javascript.

The problem is I have this multidimensional array and I'm not sure how I would write a for loop for this?

```
  $.each(wordcount, function(w, i) {
      if (i > 1) {
          constrain++;
          if (constrain <= 2) {
              topwords.push({
                  'word': w,
                  'freq': i
              });
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the values in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a single `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wordcount.length; i++) {
    var w = wordcount[i];
    if (i > 1) {
        constrain++;
        if (constrain <= 2) {
            topwords.push({
               'word': w,
                'freq': i
            });
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Oh yes I see - I can use .length :)

Comment: @AmyNeville That's the traditional way of traversing or walking through Arrays.

Comment: @AmyNeville Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

We have `Array.prototype.forEach` method in JS. You could use it like

```
wordcount.forEach(function(w, i) {
    if (i > 1) {
      constrain++;
      if (constrain <= 2) {
          topwords.push({
              'word': w,
              'freq': i
          });
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting, is that just as compatible as JQuery?

Comment: Yes indeed. Even this is more of a functional style of writing and recommended way. 
I would suggest you to also look for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  and other methods